# SharePoint lookup filters

Tags: 2013, document-library, cascading

Say you have the following:

- Planet List
- Country List
- Region List
- Town List
- Street List

Street List has a content type called "Street", which in it has a lookup to the Town List.
So the flow for creating a new street is as follows:

1. Create a planet.
2. Create a country, specify planet in dropdown.
3. Create a region, specify country in dropdown.
4. Create town, specify region in dropdown.
5. Create street, specify town in dropdown.

Each list has it's own specific properties (Planet has "SE Co-ordinates", Country has "Main language", etc..). This means that these cannot be used as managed metadata tags.

Now, I'm going to create a new document in the document library which has a content type using the "Street lookup" field.

Obviously, in the document information panel in Word - I'm going to get a gazilion different streets to choose from (including ones from other planets :P).

You can always [hack your way around it in the UI](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using). But this seems like really basic functionality - am I the first one to add addresses to documents in SharePoint??

Answer (score 0):

There are some third party solutions like [SharePoint Cascaded Lookups](https://spcd.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex, or [using jQuery](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.ru/2012/02/cascading-dropdown-or-filtered-values.html) or [Cross site and cascaded lookup](http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint/cross-site-cascaded-lookup-feature-web-part) from Virtosoftware.

Comment: Hi, could you please read the document information panel part of the question